# i can face a problem by creating a global counter when i want to show the total buyed products

Tags: javascript

this is the cart items code every cart has a separate counter but in need the global counter shows the adding of every child counter code here?

```html
<body>
 <div class="main">
      
   <div class="nav">
    <div class="total-cart-items">
        <div>Cart items ( <span id="Cart-Count">0</span> )</div>
      
    </div>
    <div class="heading">
        <h1> CartBeast</h1>
  
    </div>
   </div>
  
   <div class="product-items"  id="Product-items-div">
   </div>
   
   <div class="side-menu">
  <div class="total-amount-box">
    <div class="abox-heading">
       <h2>Total Amount Of Product</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="product-amount">
        <div>Product Price</div>
        <div>$5234</div>
    </div>
    <div class="product-charges">
        <div>Product Charges & Taxes</div>
        <div>$223</div>
    </div>
    <div class="total-charges">
        <div>Total Amount For Pay</div>
        <div>$223</div>
    </div>
    
  </div>
  <div class="discount-coupen-box">
    <div class="coupen-heading">
        <h5>Add Coupen Code for Discount</h5>
        <div> ^ </div>
    </div>
    <div class="coupen-input">
        <input type="text" class="inputtag">
    </div>
    <div class="coupen-notification">
        coupen is invalid
    </div>
    <div class="coupen-btn-div">
        <button class="coupen-apply" >Apply</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="deliver-time-box">
    <div class="deliver-heading">
        <h5>Expected Delivery Date</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="time">
    222222
    </div>
  </div>

   </div>
</body>
```

This is the Javasript code

```
   const arryofItems = [
  {
    id: 1,
    image: "./images/pngwing.com.png",
    Product_Title: "Jens Blue",
    pName: "Jens",
    PColor: "Blue",
    PSize: "34",
    datasetid: "23a-1",
    inputId: "i23a-1",
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    image: "./images/pngwing.com.png",
    Product_Title: "Jens Black",
    pName: "Jens",
    PColor: "Black",
    PSize: "34",
    datasetid: "23a-2",
    inputId: "i23a-2",
  },
];
// ********** Add product items using map in html ******
let Productitemsdiv = document.getElementById("Product-items-div");
let newitems = arryofItems.map((e) => {
  return ` <div class="cart-items" >
    <div class="cart-image"> 
       <img src="${e.image}" alt="the image" class="img">
    </div>
    <div class="cart-description">
    <div class="des-row1 des-rows">
     <div class="p-name">
     ${e.Product_Title}
     </div>
     <div class="p-count"">
       <div><i class="fa-solid minusplus fa-minus" id="${e.datasetid}" 
       onclick="decrease()"
       ></i></div>
       <input class="count" value="0" id="${e.inputId}">
       <div><i class="fa-solid minusplus fa-plus" id="${e.datasetid}"
       onclick="increase()"
       ></i></div>
     </div>

    </div>   
    <div class="des-row2">
       <div class="p-name">Name : </div>
       <div class="p-color">
           Color : ${e.PColor}
        </div>
        <div class="p-size">
        Size :
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="des-row3">
       <div class="p-delte">
           <div><i class="fa-solid fa-trash-can"></i></div>
           <div>Delete From List</div>
       </div>
       <div class="p-add-to-wishlis">
            <div><i class="fa-solid fa-heart"></i></div>
            <div>Add to WishList</div>
           
       </div>
       <div class="p-amount">
           <div class="amount">
               $234
           </div>
       </div>
    </div>
   

    </div>

   </div>`;
});
Productitemsdiv.innerHTML = newitems;
// ---------------------------------------------
// ******************** single product items count ******************
function cartitems() {
      let minusicon = document.querySelectorAll(".fa-minus");
      let global = document.getElementById("Cart-Count")
      let plusicon = document.querySelectorAll(".fa-plus");
      var globelcounter =0;
      minusicon.forEach((e) => {
        e.onclick = function decrease(v) {
          let i = "i";
          let Id = v.currentTarget.id;
          let input = document.getElementById(i + Id);
          if (input.value < 2) {
            input.value = 0;
          } else {
            input.value = parseInt(input.value) - 1;
            globelcounter = input.value;
            global.textContent = globelcounter;
          }
        };
      });
      plusicon.forEach((e) => {
        e.onclick = function increase(v) {
          let i = "i";
          let Id = v.currentTarget.id;
          let input = document.getElementById(i + Id);
          input.value = parseInt(input.value) + 1;
          globelcounter = input.value;
          global.textContent = globelcounter;
        };
      });
}
cartitems();
// ---------------------------------------------

// *************************************************
```

Global variable in these functions cannot work? what kind of mistake is taken by me? code is working fine but the child counter value of one cart is increased then if we click the second one the value starts to 0. A global variable cannot add both carts.

Comment: There is no global variable defined in the code you showed.

Answer (score -1):

This is not complete code you have shared regarding  issue. and you have put one condition like if there is count < 2 then input.value = 0; for minus click.
please share complete code and put the exact issue.
Thanks.

Comment: its complete code